# Redirect from subdomain to primary domain without rewriting URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've been searching similar solutions but none of them seems working on my server.

What I'm trying to do is set redirect from **yyy.zzz.com** (subdomain) to **zzz.com** (primary domain) *without* rewriting url. So both **yyy.zzz.com** and **zzz.com** actually pointing at same directory and same files in it.

Currently I have this **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yyy\.zzz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://zzz.com [L,NC]
```

Which, of course, just redirects straight on, and url actually changes.

Just for information, I want to set such subdomain url for CMS, so if user wants to enter CMS he does it from subdomain, while actually only $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is changing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot do internal redirect if the domain changes even if its a sub domain of the main domain. By default the web server will redirect when the domain's are different as in `yyy.zzz.com` is different than `zzz.com` so it will redirect.

Comment: Well, I'm not fully understand it, but is there any way I could do similar thing?

Comment: @Grimv01k: Can you enable `mod_proxy` enabled on your server?

Comment: @anubhava: I've seen your answers on similar issue at SO, but unfortunately I can't enable it : (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up a ServerAlias in your apache config. Setting yyy.zzz.com as an alias for zzz.com

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName zzz.com
ServerAlias yyy.zzz.com
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: Great stuff, the only thing that worries me a bit is SEO, but I think I could handle that. Maybe there are some other issues I'm not aware of, though... Thank you!